# Encrypt pdf/docx files with header

Tags: pdf, encryption, header, corrupt

I'm developing an application that not only ciphers the pdf/docx documents, but also add a header before all the real data of the document. For example, a pdf file with the header but without being ciphered, would look like:

**headercontent
%PDF................**

The problem is that I've noticed that if you modify the pdf content once and then revert it, the file remeains corrupt. Example:

Let's say we have a pdf file that starts with **%PDF-1.4** and I modify it to be something like **test%PDF-1.4**. This file is corrupt right now. So, I revert the changes and it looks like **%PDF-1.4** again. If I try to open the pdf file now, it is still corrupt.

I've already read this https://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/kb/pdf-error-1015-11001-update.html and it's not the case because I'm removing those bytes and it is still corrupt.

FYI, I'm modifying it with a Hex Editor so there is no garbage before %PDF.

Do you have any ideas of what is happening? Where is the "corrupt file flag" hidden?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is much more to a valid PDF file than a magic marker.

Comment: That's what I'm trying to guess. Where is that "corrupt PDF flag" or "valid PDF flag" or whatever you want to call it? Thanks

Comment: Adding the header after it is encrypted will likely be more useful.  Additionally, using a character as a splitter in a binary file is generally considered a poor idea.  Use a length prefixed string instead.

Comment: In fact that's what I'm doing. Adding the header after being encrypted. The problem comes when I decrypt it and remove the header, the pdf is still corrupt. So I just did a try with a simple header ("test") and without encryption, to check that the problem is the pdf file and not my encryption/header.

Comment: It should work as you describe it. So, it seems you have a problem with your code. Please [edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete and Verifyable example](/help/mcve) of your issue.

Comment: *"Let's say we have a pdf file that starts with %PDF-1.4 and I modify it to be something like test%PDF-1.4. This file is corrupt right now. So, I revert the changes and it looks like %PDF-1.4 again. If I try to open the pdf file now, it is still corrupt."* - then your process did not really revert all changes.  Please compare the files and look for changes.

Comment: You should remove the header THEN decrypt...  I think you are misunderstanding.